# Perform Django join and group by over jsonb fields

Tags: django, django-orm, jsonb

I've run through all Django sources about annotation, aggregation, still 
can't understand how to implement the following query with Django ORM.

This example is not from production, but rather educational therefore it may differ from best practices.

I need the query that will output the count of houses per each color that exists in the Colors table:

```
select
    clr.id as colorId, count(*) as count

from colors as clr
inner join houses as c
on clr.id = cast(c.parameters ->> 'colorId' as int)
group by colorId;
```

Data schema is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE colors (
  id serial primary key NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE houses (
  id serial primary key NOT NULL,
  parameters jsonb NOT NULL
);

insert into colors (id, name) values

(1, 'red'),
(2, 'green'),
(3, 'blue'),
(4, 'other');

insert into houses (parameters) values

('{"price": 1000, "colorId": 1}'),
('{"price": 2000, "colorId": 2}'),
('{"price": 2500, "colorId": 2}'),
('{"price": 3000, "colorId": 3}'),
('{"price": 3100, "colorId": 3}'),
('{"price": 3200, "colorId": 3}');
```

What would be implementation with Django ORM?
Simple queries are pretty straightforward, but I miss something to understand about aggregation and annotation over jsonb fields

Here is the model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField, TextField
from django.db import models

class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class House(models.Model):
    parameters = models.JSONField()
```

That query should be like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Houses.objects.values('color').annotate(dcount=Count('color'))
```

But Houses table doesn't have the ForeignKey to Colors, instead, it has colorid with json parameters

Comment: Hi Dmitry - would it be ok to see the Houses and Colors tables please in your `models.py` file...

Comment: @MichealJRoberts Hi Micheal, I've added the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the way you set up your model, you don't actually need the join (even in the SQL).  Also from the ORM point of view, this is a pretty strange way to have pseudo-related models that aren't explicitly related (i.e., with a ForeignKey).  That said, the missing link in your queryset is the KeyTextTransform which is (currently) not very well documented but can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb/):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
from django.db.models import Count

Houses.objects.annotate(
    color_id=KeyTextTransform('colorId', 'parameters')
).values(
    'color_id'
).annotate(
    dcount=Count('color_id')
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close, I forgot to mention that I need to group by only over colors that exist in the Colors table. So inner join is actually necessary

Comment: I agree with you, very weird pseudo relational model, this is not production, just educatonal

Comment: is this possible?
dcount=Count('color_id', filter=Q(color_id__in=Subquery(Color.values('id'))))

Comment: Provided my last comment is correct, I will take your answer